# How can I remove all old nodes in Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I created some nodes in Zookeeper use CLI, but i forgot the node's authentication, I tried to re-install the zookeeper,it did not work.
Any body can help me? mac

Answer (score 0):

Use command ==>mdfind -name "zookeeper"

Remove all relative files.

http://osxdaily.com/2014/07/31/manual-complete-app-removal-mac-os-x-terminal/